# Init OrdImage object without inserting anything to DB

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am trying to retrieve OrdImage object from Oracle database using selection over dual table (select ordsys.ordimage.init() from dual) due to usage in OrdImageSinature creation for search purposes in IMGSimilar operator. Problem is, that after storing data in ORDImage proxy I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 797
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDSOURCE", line 778
ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE", line 508
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

My code is following:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
OracleResultSet result = (OracleResultSet) statement.executeQuery("SELECT ordsys.ordimage.init(), ordsys.ordimagesignature.init() FROM DUAL");

if (result.next()) {
    OrdImage imageProxy = (OrdImage) result.getORAData(1, OrdImage.getORADataFactory());
    OrdImageSignature imageSignatureProxy = (OrdImageSignature) result.getORAData(2, OrdImageSignature.getORADataFactory());

    statement.close();
    result.close();

    imageProxy.loadDataFromByteArray(image.write().toByteArray()); //this line invokes error
    imageProxy.setProperties();
    imageSignatureProxy.generateSignature(imageProxy);

    //here will be performed search operation
}
```

Image which I am placing in imageProxy is stored locally on HDD (it is not stored in database). Is there any workaround how to create OrdImageSignature without creating OrdImage to bypass this error or how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
// retrieve dummy Oracle Mm Java objects from the database
        OrdImage imgProxy = null;
        OrdImageSignature sigProxy = null;
        OracleCallableStatement cstmtOrdImageCreator = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(
                "DECLARE"
                + "  IMG ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE;"
                + "  SIG ORDSYS.ORDIMAGESIGNATURE;"
                + "  IMGBLOB BLOB;"
                + "  SIGBLOB BLOB;"
                + "BEGIN"
                + "  IMG := ORDImage.init();" // init an image
                + "  DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(IMG.source.localdata, TRUE);" // an emply BLOB for the image
                + "  SIG := ORDImageSignature.init();" // init a signature of the image
                + "  DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(SIG.signature, TRUE);" // an emply BLOB for its signature
                + "  ? := IMG;" // return both the image and its signature as values of output parameters
                + "  ? := SIG;"
                + "END;");
        try {
            cstmtOrdImageCreator.registerOutParameter(1,
                    OrdImage._SQL_TYPECODE, OrdImage._SQL_NAME);
            cstmtOrdImageCreator.registerOutParameter(2,
                    OrdImageSignature._SQL_TYPECODE, OrdImageSignature._SQL_NAME);
            cstmtOrdImageCreator.executeUpdate();
            imgProxy = (OrdImage) cstmtOrdImageCreator.getORAData(1, OrdImage.getORADataFactory());
            sigProxy = (OrdImageSignature) cstmtOrdImageCreator.getORAData(2, OrdImageSignature.getORADataFactory());
        } finally {
            cstmtOrdImageCreator.close();
        }
```